# Decode cyrillic HTML entities in C#

Tags: c#, html, cyrillic

I have some `string` taken from website using `HtmlAgilityPack`, that contains HTML entities of *cyrillic letters*

**Example:**

```
"&Kcy;&ocy;&rcy;&pcy;&ucy;&scy;"
```

Is there any way to decode it into symbols in **C#** when saving to file? I tried using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` and `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` of `System.Web`, but it *didn't help*.

**My attempt:**

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace esp
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            body = "&Kcy;&ocy;&rcy;&pcy;&ucy;&scy;";

            //output will be "&Kcy;&ocy;&rcy;&pcy;&ucy;&scy;"
            Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(body)); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include a [mcve] of what you tried so far.

Comment: Try the entity decoding method from HtmlAgilityPack: `HtmlEntity.DeEntitize`.

Comment: HtmlEntitiy.DeEntitize didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a *guess*. As far as I can see, we have the following format:

```
  &
   Letter(s) - transliterated letter 
   cy        - stands for Cyrillic 
  ;
```

We can *match* all the letters with a help of *Regular expressions*, and `Concat` them into a `string` e.g.

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string body = "&Kcy;&ocy;&rcy;&pcy;&ucy;&scy;";

  var transliteratedText = Regex.Replace(
         body, 
       @"&(?<letter>[A-Za-z]+)cy;",
         m => m.Groups["letter"].Value);

  Console.Write(transliteratedText);
```

And we'll have

```
Korpus
```

which sounds reasonable, since it's [transliterated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALA-LC_romanization_for_Russian) Russian word **Корпус** (`Corpus`, `Body`, `Bulk`, `Carcass`). There are *several* transliteration standards (I've tried *Library of Congress* scheme which is just one of the most popular); in order to detect the *right standard* (or create our own) we want *more* data.

**Edit** For instance if we have a scheme, say,

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> translit = 
  new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
  {"a", "а"},
  {"b", "б"},
  {"v", "в"},
  {"g", "г"},
  {"d", "д"},
  {"ie", "е"},
  //{"", "ё"}, //TODO: define the letter transliteration
  {"zh", "ж"},
  {"z", "з"},
  {"i", "и"},
  {"j", "й"},
  {"k", "к"},
  {"l", "л"},
  {"m", "м"},
  {"n", "н"},
  {"o", "о"},
  {"p", "п"},
  {"r", "р"},
  {"s", "с"},
  {"t", "т"},
  {"u", "у"},
  {"f", "ф"},
  {"h", "х"},
  {"ts", "ц"},
  {"ch", "ч"},
  {"sh", "ш"},
  {"shch", "щ"},
  //{"", "ъ"}, //TODO: define the letter transliteration
  {"y", "ы"},
  //{"", "ь"}, //TODO: define the letter transliteration
  //{"", "э"}, //TODO: define the letter transliteration
  //{"", "ю"}, //TODO: define the letter transliteration
  {"ya", "я"},
};
```

we can transliterate each letter:

```
private static string MyDecoding(string value) {
  return Regex
    .Replace(value, @"&(?<letter>[A-Za-z]+)cy;", m => {
      string v = m.Groups["letter"].Value;

      return char.IsUpper(v[0])
        ? CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(translit[v])
        : translit[v];
      }
    );
}
...

Console.Write(MyDecoding("&Kcy;&ocy;&rcy;&pcy;&ucy;&scy;"));
```

**Outcome:**

```
Корпус
```

Comment: I've noticed that format either. ch stands for "ч", y for "ы", j for "й", ya for "я", ie for "e" ,ts for "ц", shch for "щ". So, basically, there's no "easy" way to decode these entities and I should do it myself with regular expressions in either getting these symbols out of entity and replacing it with matching cyrillic symbol?

Comment: @Chelicerae: I doubt if there's an easy *standard* way to convert the string: 
we have *several* transliterations standards which are often *ambiguous* (`"shch" -> "щ" or "шч"`).
That's why transliterations is technically *one way process*: we can easily turn Cyrillic text
into English (say, to represent Russian author's name for the Library of Congress), but reverse process 
is very complex and uncertain.